# Error when trying to browse WCF Application from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7

we have a WCF service which is hosted on IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2. the service hosted on IIS is giving the below error

[image]

we have the service working on another server with the same configurations.

please let me know what exactly i can verify to see if settings are right

Comment: Is your website in a virtual directory? If so it's possible that the parent site is restricting some settings in its Web.config file meaning that you can't add your own `appSettings` section.

Answer (score 0):

follow the below mentioned step

1. Press on Start button
2. in the search box, enter Turn windows features on or off
3. in the features window, Click: Internet Information Services
4. Click: World Wide Web Services
5. Click: Application Development Features
6. Check (enable) the features. I checked all but CGI.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer from @DhavalPatel does not work, then it could be the framework version.  On IIS, go to the application pool for the application in question.  It is more often than not on .Net2 - change it to 4 if you are using > 3.5.